# JPA OneToMany Cascade

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

we are developing an application in which we have a tree-structure. Using Java EE and JPA (EclipseLink) and MySQL.

My Problem:
Saving the parent causes saving all childs.
I removed the CascadeType PERSIST and MERGE but still it cascades.

Example Code: 
Parent Node:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node")
@NamedQuery(name = "node.findAll", query = "SELECT n FROM Node n")
public class Node implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapKey(name = "name")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "name")
    @JoinColumn(name = "NODE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Map<String, Data> datas = new HashMap<String, Data>();
```

And the Child Node:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data")
@NamedQuery(name = "data.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Data d")
@IdClass(DataId.class)
public class Data implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

The parent node "Node" has also a parent called System. The code is similar to Node and Data. There are 8 Levels, but all are similar, using OneToMany relation to build the tree.
Is it possible to avoid saving the Data (Child) objects when im saving the Node (Parent). Or for example i want to save an object from level 6 (System Node) so it should not persist or merge the child nodes.

Because im receiving some Nodes and Datas from a Client per REST and i want to save the Node immidiately but the Data objects later using a thread which checks which Datas are new and save only them.

Comment: How are you going to retrieve all the information you need if you do not save it? Yes you can save the nodes immediately only if the foreinged key exists in the database. @OneToMany creates a one-to-many connection in the databse with foreinged keys.

Comment: Checking what is new and saving only changes is what JPA is designed to do with the merge functionality. Since your OneToMany is required to update the foreign key within the Data table, there is no way for this to be accomplished without some way of already having Data managed to maintain the relationship. You might want to do your Node processing after the Data instances, and replace the data instances within node with the managed ones you've read/merged though JPA.

Comment: Alright, thank you guys. But is there any other possible solution to make it work that i can save the Node but still have the "same" relationship to Data?

Comment: Your model is flawed for the design you state you want. You might be able to take the Node passed in from your api and manually merge what you want into the Node you read in from an entityManager, thereby avoiding changing your datas map.  You then will be missing any changes to this collection unless you somehow handle this in your 'data' handling later on.